# PHP - Adding Multiple Arrays for a JSON package in Wordpress / Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to build a JSON package using PHP and having issues with the formatting.

Here's the format that I'm after:

```
{
    "SenderSuburb": "xxxx",
    "SenderState": "xxx",
    "SenderPostcode": "xxx",
    "ReceiverSuburb": "xxx",
    "ReceiverState": "xxx",
    "ReceiverPostcode": "xxx",
    "CustomerName": "xxx",
    "CustomerCode": "xx",
    "Rows": [{
        "QtyDecimal": 1,
        "Weight": 100,
        "Length": 0.5,
        "Width": 0.3,
        "Height": 0.2,
        "Description": "Carton"
    }],
    "Rows": [{
        "QtyDecimal": 1,
        "Weight": 100,
        "Length": 0.5,
        "Width": 0.3,
        "Height": 0.2,
        "Description": "Carton"
    }]
}
```

At the moment, it's printing the right JSON format but when it comes to adding multiple rows, it only adds one row not multiple.

I tried array_push but wasn't able to get it to work.

Here's my code:

```
$thearray = array();
$thearray[SenderSuburb] = "xxx";
$thearray[SenderState] = "xxx";
$thearray[SenderPostcode] = "xxx";
$thearray[ReceiverSuburb] = "xxx";
$thearray[ReceiverState] = "xxx";
$thearray[ReceiverPostcode] = "xxx";
$thearray[CustomerName] = "xxx";
$thearray[CustomerCode] = "xxx";

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
            
    $item_name = $cart_item['data']->get_title();
    $item_weight = $cart_item['data']->get_weight();
    $item_height = $cart_item['data']->get_height();
    $item_width = $cart_item['data']->get_width();
    $item_length = $cart_item['data']->get_length();
            
    $thearray[Rows] = array([
        'QtyDecimal' => '1', 
        'Weight' => $item_weight,
        'Length' => $item_length,
        'Width' => $item_width,
        'Height' => $item_height,
        'Description' => $item_name
    ]);
    

}
        
    print("<pre>".print_r($thearray,true)."</pre>");
    $entire_array_JSON = json_encode($thearray);
    echo $entire_array_JSON;
```

and here's the output:

```
Array
(
    [SenderSuburb] => xxxx
    [SenderState] => xxx
    [SenderPostcode] => xxx
    [ReceiverSuburb] => xxxx
    [ReceiverState] => xxx
    [ReceiverPostcode] => xxx
    [CustomerName] => xxxx
    [CustomerCode] => xxxx
    [Rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [QtyDecimal] => 1
                    [Weight] => 8
                    [Length] => 60
                    [Width] => 40
                    [Height] => 2
                    [Description] => xxxxx
                )

        )

)
```

and the decoded JSON response:

```
{
    "SenderSuburb": "xxxx",
    "SenderState": "xxx",
    "SenderPostcode": "xxx",
    "ReceiverSuburb": "xxx",
    "ReceiverState": "xxx",
    "ReceiverPostcode": "xxx",
    "CustomerName": "xxx",
    "CustomerCode": "xxx",
    "Rows": [{
        "QtyDecimal": "1",
        "Weight": "8",
        "Length": "60",
        "Width": "40",
        "Height": "2",
        "Description": "xxxx"
    }]
}
```

As you can see, it only displays one row not multiple rows particularly when there's multiple products in the shopping cart.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Since PHP doesn't allow duplicate keys, I had to assign only one key and add multiple values to that key using array_push.

$thearray[Rows] = array();